# Could this be a choice function for powersets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I think following could be a choice function for choosing from powersets of $\mathbb{R} - \{\emptyset\}$ which is said to be only possible by axiom of choice. I am doing something wrong, esp. following is against axioms of set theory(may be infinity) but how? Or the definition of this function is wrong?

$f: \{x+\sqrt{2}/10^x : x \in \mathbb{N} \}= \{\ \{\sqrt{2}/10\}, \{1+\sqrt{2}/100\}, \{2+\sqrt{2}/1000\}, ... \}$

**Edit:** Actually, I want to choose from integer interval subsets of reals like; { [0,1), [1,2), [2,3),... }

(Sorry for my informal notation but you get the point I think)

Comment: A choice function would be a function whose domain is **all possible** non-empty subsets of $\Bbb R$.  The domain of your suggested $f$ does not appear to be all possible non-empty subsets.

Comment: I have no idea what you definition of $f$ is supposed to mean, or how it is supposed to be a choice function.  Also, the two sets you have connected with an equals sign are not equal.

Comment: @RobertShore You are right i missed that point, it does not span all sets.

Comment: I think the downvote and vote to close are somewhat harsh.  The poster knew that the question likely was overlooking something, and asked for help finding it.  That seems to me a perfectly appropriate use of the site.

Comment: @EricWofsey i forget to add integers. Actually i want to select from integer interval subsets of reals like { [0,1), [1,2), [2,3),... } but could not express it in formal mathematical notation and not sure even possible to express it.

Comment: @lockedscope: Choosing from intervals of the form $[n,n+1)$ for $n\in\Bbb N$? Just choose $n$.

Comment: Actually my set will be $ \{ [0, \sqrt{2}/10,...,1), [1, 1+\sqrt{2}/100,..., 2),... \}$. Each of those subsets are infinite, all irrationals included in that interval. So, is not it possible to select an irrational with the rule given in my post? @AsafKaragila but as you said, selecting 0,1,2 also would be fine. I could not grasp some point about axiom of choice

Comment: I think that as a start you should read about the standard ways to write and denote sets. $[0,\sqrt2/10,\dots,1)$ is not a thing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are right that is my shortcoming. So, i realized that my main set does not include all powersets. So, in some set, those integers are not included and in some of them $x+\sqrt{2}/10^x$ is not included. My mistake was neglecting the power set part of the axiom of choice. So, its clear to me i think.

Comment: But again, i wonder why could not we just select the smallest from each set? We could not specify the smallest like using a min function in programming so we should tell it how, right?

Comment: Actually i see that we cannot select min, max from an irrational interval. Also we cannot select from middle because some of the sets(a set which is an element in main set) have no middle. Thus choice function seems impossible. But how could it be with axiom of choice is unknown too. May be there is a math function to select it we don't know. A robot or a program might select but would it be valid for math?

Comment: I find it easy to think with powersets, instead of cartesian product definition of axiom of choice. For cartesian product, when the number of sets infinite and when each of them have infinite number of sets then they seem similar to power sets. So, when those finite members with finite contents of powersets neglected then powersets and cartesian products became equivalent, right?

Comment: I suppose cartesian product is a usual cartesian product but i realized that it is about indexed family of sets. So, its clear now that it is similar to powersets definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It couldn't be. It is consistent with $\sf ZF$ that there is no such function, and therefore you cannot possibly define one explicitly.

You are also defining the function on a very specific collection of sets, it seems. There are *a lot* more sets which do not have this form. What is the choice from them?

If you want a concrete challenge, fix a bijection $f$ between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb{R^N}$, the set of all infinite sequences of real numbers, now for each countable set $A$ let $F_A=\{x\in\Bbb R \mid A=\operatorname{rng}(f(x))\}$, namely $F_A$ is all those sequences which enumerate (with repeating) exactly all the elements of $A$.

I dare you to find an explicit choice function from $\{F_A\mid A\subseteq\Bbb R \text{ and countable}\}$.